# Как обновить форму при изменении данных в БД?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server

Есть два одинаковых приложения winforms у двух разных юзеров. Работают они с одной таблицей (но в разных формах). Первая форма для добавления, вторая для наблюдения. 
Как сделать так, чтобы при добавлении записи первым юзером в таблицу, у второго запись сразу же добавилась автоматически?

Comment: Какая СУБД используется?

Comment: Two-forms-one-tab

Comment: Как насчет написать веб сервис, который будет работать с базой и с которыми будут работать ваши приложения? :)

Comment: @AGS17 сервис, это "запросщик" на таблицу ?который будет рассылать команды для обновления интерфейса ?
Если так то это нагрузка думаю слишком большая по сравнению с тем, что можно уведомлять интерфейс только при изменении (а не читать постоянно). Или по другому как то?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Субд - mssql

Comment: @Snainer, смотрите в сторону [SqlDependency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: DataGridView юзаете?

Comment: Можете в сервисе использовать SignalR, он будет уведомлять клиентов после обновления данных

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю использовать асинхронные вызовы, проверял на своем проекте

```
private async void GetDv(ServerListener sl)
    {
        Func<Task> testFunc = async () =>
        {                
            dataGridView1.Refresh();                            
            //задержка на 1 секунду обновления
            await Task.Delay(1000);               
        };
        while (true)
        {              
                await testFunc();                  
        }
    }
```

Можно это вставить в Form_Load

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать таблицу, которая содержит дату последнего обновления.

Вешаем триггер на основную таблицу, за которой нужно следить и данный триггер при любых обновлениях обновляет дату во вспомогательной таблице.

Далее клиенты опрашивают это вспомогательную таблицу и считывают дату, если дата на клиентах!= той, что во вспомогательной => обновляем дату на клиенте и читаем данные из основной таблицы.

Вроде, все красиво.

Правда, триггер может тормозить таблицу. Хотя... логика довольно тупая=> триггер должен быть легковесным.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать любую реактивную базу данных. И не обязательно SQL.

В таком случае можно просто **подписатся на изменения в любой из таблиц**.

Лично я работал с Realm у которой даный функционал есть. Но реалм под шарпом несколько топорный и имеет множество нюансов (в т.ч. недокументированных) так что, наверное, лучше использовать другую базу данных поддерживающую реактивность...

Но можно и реалм.